# Golang RestApi Mysql Insert Query

Tags: go

I am a noob to Golang, trying to create RestApi which gets requests from the postman and storing it in MYSQL.
while trying to Insert a row which has two columns (name and title) but one column is always null while inserting into DB, could you please let me know how to add multiple fields.

```
func createPost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO posts(name,title) VALUES(?,?)")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    keyVal := make(map[string]string)
    json.Unmarshal(body, &keyVal)
    name := keyVal["name"]
    title := keyVal["title"]
    _, err = stmt.Exec(name, title)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}




JSON Request :
{
    "name":"John"
    "title":"Engineer"
}
```

Comment: sorry Its one column is null after inserting

Comment: Look at the error returned from json.Unmarshal. If that's really the request json, it is invalid. It needs comma after the "name":"John" pair.

Comment: @Burak Serdar Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First check `Unmarshal` error, maybe your request is not right.

If you post correctly, your JSON request is missing a comma:

```
{
 "name":"John" <<<<<<<< comma here
 "title":"Engineer"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first convert the json you are recieving using a function like-

```
func FromJSON(i interface{}, r io.Reader) error {
    d := json.NewDecoder(r)
    return d.Decode(i)
}
```

if there is still any problem then probably the problem is with the comma while sending the request, if you are using postman
the request should be
{
"name":"John",
"title":"Engineer",
}